# Finding compatibility of GeoServer versions to PostgreSQL / PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, compatibility, postgresql-13

We have an older version of GeoServer (2.8) which was installed as part of the Open Suite 4.8 bundle from Boundless (which doesn't exist any longer).  This Geoserver instance connects to a Windows server hosting an older version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS (9.6.2 and 2.3). We are now migrating our PostgreSQL and PostGIS instances to 13 and 3.1.4 respectively (on a Linux server).

We also have a test Linux server using PostgreSQL 11 and PostGIS 2. (this was set up months ago).

Our old GeoServer can connect to and publish from this test server, but we get back errors trying to publish from the newer versions of PostgreSQL / PostGIS.

Can anyone point me to online documentation that shows which version of GeoServer is compatible with what version of PostGIS and PostgreSQL?

Also, I am assuming incompatibility is the problem here, but could there be something else going on?

EDIT: here is an error message from Geoserver log - we copied this function from old PostGIS function list  to the new server db, and it seems like that fixed the issue (we can now publish services from old Geoserver connected to new Linux server with PostGreSQL 13)..but I am still concerned we may find other problems down the line.

```
WARN [geotools.jdbc] - Failed to use ST_Estimated_Extent, falling back on envelope aggregation
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function st_estimated_extent(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

Comment: I don't think there is a dependency, but try updating the postgis JDBC jar to match the latest version. Alternatively please [edit] the question with the error messages

Comment: ok, i can add more info - btw I should have mentioned our old Geoserver instance if part of the Open Suite 4.8 bundle from (now defunct) Bounldess

Comment: see edits in original post

Answer (score 4):

`ST_Estimates_Extent` has been available since version 1.0 of PostGIS but was changed to [`ST_EstimatedExtent` in version 2.1.0](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_EstimatedExtent.html).

I was intrigued by this question so I went and looked at the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/f5ece02748173969cc359727d73de5a6d35e153d/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostGISDialect.java#L1493) (one of my favourite open source rights) and
GeoTools (the library that underlies GeoServer) should handle this just fine no matter which version of PostGIS you use if you are using a version since 15.0 (about [6 years ago](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5378)).

You are running a very old version of GeoServer so I would recommend upgrading to a recent version like 2.19.

Comment: thanks. I was asking more specifically about any online documentation detailing compatible versions of Geoserver to Postgres / PostGIS but this info is helpful...
However, my office blocks access to sourceforge.  I see you are one of the developers of Geoserver, do you know anywhere else I can find the Geoserver 2.20 Windows installer that I see is now available?

Comment: The only other option would be to contract a commercial supplier to do the install or smuggle a copy in from home

Comment: ok -we found a workaround, thanks